# TabbedPage navigation error - "No view found for id 0x7f0a018b [...]"

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I'm trying to create a TabbedPage view on the company app.

First of all, to assure evertything is working, I created a XAML ContentPage *MyTabbedPage*, and configured the Dependency Injection for it on the MauiProgram.cs just like on the other views

`mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<MyTabbedPage>();`

On my main page, I navigate to it using a button that is binded to this command

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private async Task Create() => await _navigationService.NavigateToPage<MyTabbedPage>();
```

This is the NavigateToPage method on the _navigationService:

```cs
        public async Task NavigateToPage<T>(object? parameter = null) where T : Page
        {
            var toPage = ResolvePage<T>();

            if (toPage is not null)
            {
                //Subscribe to the toPage's NavigatedTo event
                toPage.NavigatedTo += PageNavigatedTo;

                //Get VM of the toPage
                var toViewModel = GetPageViewModelBase(toPage);

                //Call navigatingTo on VM, passing in the parameter
                if (toViewModel is not null)
                    await toViewModel.OnNavigatingTo(parameter);

                //Navigate to requested page
                await Navigation.PushAsync(toPage, true);

                //Subscribe to the toPage's NavigatedFrom event
                toPage.NavigatedFrom += PageNavigatedFrom;
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to resolve type {typeof(T).FullName}");
        }
```

And it works as expected.

But what I really need is a TabbedPage, so I change the ContentPage to a TabbedPage (on both the XAML and the xaml.cs files), and set the children of the TabbedPage, so the XAML is now this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MyTabbedPage"
             Title="MyTabbedPage">

    <views:MyChildrenPage/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Now, when I press the button to navigate to it, I get the error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x7f0a018b (CONFIDENTIALPATH/navigationlayout_toptabs) for fragment ViewFragment{a6b7d12} (fec1b5a7-e8fa-4129-a651-e8c4978783fb id=0x7f0a018b)'
```

*CONFIDENTIALPATH -> censored path with the name of the company's app.

I tried without the children, and also with a fresh ContentPage as a children, but the problem seems to be with the TabbedPage itself because I still get the same error.

Some information that might be useful:

- I couldn't find anything about this error on the internet, besides the "same error" on other languages/frameworks, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940192/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f090005). None of those were caused by tabs, and they also didn't help me understand the problem.
- I'd like to avoid using Shell stuff if possible.
- I'm following [Microsoft's TabbedPage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-tabbedpage).
- I'm using MVVM, so the MyChildrenPage view has a binding with its ViewModel as follows

```cs
public partial class MyChildrenPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyChildrenPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Done this way because TabbedPage will complain if the children has a constructor with 
        //parameters, even tho Microsoft tells us to use MVVM. How ironic huh?
        var viewModel = Application.Current.MainPage.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<MyChildrenViewModel>();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Per [Navigate within a tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0#navigate-within-a-tab), you may need wrap the `CotenPage`: MyChildrenPage within a `NaviagtionPage`. If that doesn't work, please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via Github link. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I don't think this is the problem, since the TabbedPage won't work even with no children on it at all, so I believe the error is before the "rendering" of the children.
I'll try to create a small example and see if I get this error to trigger.

Comment: Look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @FernandoLopes Any progress on this one? Facing the exact same issue